# Read specific text from file

Tags: c#

I have a text file with the following information

```
     Caracas, 08 de Julio       de 2016
     SAVAKE CA
     Estimado HANS AJANI
     D        1089274             101548895              444.825,68 BS
```

i have a code that reads all the lines and prints them in the cmd:

```
        string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(@"p:\CARTAP1.txt");
        foreach (string s in readText)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

I can read the lines by using Console.WriteLine(readText[3]) but how can i get specific information in an array, for example only 1089272.

How do i get those number separately instead of getting them in a line all together?

Comment: using string.Split(...

Comment: You could get your string from readText[] and then readText[3].split(' '), which would split the row into another array of strings split based on the spaces?  Kind of messy, but I think might work for your situation.

Comment: How is the data organized? Please update your answer with a typical format. Are the 4 lines of data complete? Do they repeat? Do all files follow the same formatting?

Comment: You can use the `string.Split` method.

Comment: Please don't put languages in question titles; put the language in the tags

Comment: Hi Sunny, the text document only has that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By splitting the string

```
string input = "     D        1089274             101548895              444.825,68 BS";
string result = input.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
```

Comment: Hey, thanks that gives me that valor, but reading the code it stores only 1089274 to the variable, but i also need the other 2 values "101548895              444.825,68 BS"

Comment: I got it now! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are the lines tab delimited? If so you can split the string 's' like so

```
var items =  s.Split('\t')
```

Comment: What do you mean bt delimited?

Comment: It appears that there are some spaces between your data. I'm not sure if you pasted it directly and they are indeed an arbitrary set of spaces or if they are tabs? delimited just means separated by.

Comment: Oh ok, actually that txt is generated by an application so i actually dont know why the spaces where placed. thanks